# Trouble Querying Against int Field using MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

Hey, 
I'm trying to run the following query:

```
     self.cursor.execute('SELECT courses.courseid, days, starttime, bldg, roomnum, '
                    'area, title, descrip, prereqs, endtime FROM '
                    'classes, courses, crosslistings, coursesprofs, profs WHERE '
                    'classes.courseid = courses.courseid AND '
                    'courses.courseid = crosslistings.courseid AND '
                    'courses.courseid = coursesprofs.courseid AND '
                    'coursesprofs.profid = profs.profid AND '
                    'classes.classid LIKE %s'
                    ';',
                    (self.classid))
```

classid is an int(11) field in the db. When I set self.classid = %, it returns all the results, but as soon as I set it to say, '3454' or some other amount it returns nothing even when there is a class with that classid. Am I querying incorrectly against int fields?

Even a simpler query like
select * from classes where classes.classid = '3454'; does not work

Comment: You should use `=` instead of `LIKE` for integer columns. `LIKE` will cause the column value and the parameter to be converted to strings and compared as such, which is certainly slower than int comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this on my own. Based on my db structure, I was querying the wrong fields. I was looking for values that weren't there so that's why I was always returning an empty result set. Thanks for the help on the = operator though, that was utilized.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> select * from classes where classes.classid = 3454;